# extract semicolon separated value from pandas df column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to extract a specific value from pandas df column. The data looks like this:

```
row        my_column
1          artid=delish.recipe.45064;artid=delish_recipe_45064;avb=83.3;role=4;data=list;prf=i
2          ab=px_d_1200;ab=2;ab=t_d_o_1000;artid=delish.recipe.23;artid=delish;role=1;pdf=true
3          dat=_o_1000;artid=delish.recipe.23;ar;role=56;passing=true;points001
```

The data is not consistent, but separated by a comma and I need to extract `role=x`.
I separated the data by a semicolon. And can loop trough the values to fetch the roles, but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve it.
Desired output:

```
row        my_column
1          role=4
2          role=1
3          role=56
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the code/regex that fails for you? Please share to see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` and pass the required pattern within parentheses.

```
df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].str.extract('(role=\d+)')

   row  my_column
0    1     role=4
1    2     role=1
2    3    role=56
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def get_role(x):
    l=x.split(sep=';')
    t=[i for i in l if i[:4]=='role')][0]
    return t

df['my_column']=[i for i in map(lambda y: get_role(y), df['my_column'])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have this error: `t=[i for i in l if i[:4]=='role']
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Can you try again please?

Comment: The same error, unfortunately. `t=[i for i in l if (len(i)>5 and i[:4]=='role')][0] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: `str.extract('(role=\d+)')` worked for me and seems easier in one line of code. Thank you for your help. I upvoted your answer.